# Selenium Wait Issues while testing ember js applications

Tags: selenium, automated-tests

I am currently automating selenium testcases for a web application that was ported from simple jsp with javascript to ember js  framework.

The old application had **iframes** and the testcases written had selenium's wait for `frametobeavailableandswitch` method for **iframe** switch  and it worked properly.Also for waiting for the applications page load the **testcases** used to check `document.readyState` using `JavascriptExecutor` after every action to confirm the page and all elements have been loaded.

The new application also uses iframes but selenium's `frametobeavailableandswitch` method is not working properly.The **iframe** switch is happening but it doesn't wait for the contents in the iframe to load.The next element i click after switching to the frame fails.
    Also the `document.readyState` is returning as complete before the page even loads completely.

I am unable to provide the application as its a locally installable tomcat server application.

Has anyone faced these kinds of issues automating ember js application with java selenium.

Plese provide any ideas for this problem. I am testing them using selenium 3 java and **chromedriver** on windows.

**Sample Code:**

```
public class IframeSwitchAndWaitProblem {

public static void main(String args[])
{

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "e:\\chromedriver.exe");

    ChromeDriver driver =new ChromeDriver();

    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    driver.get("http://localhost:9090");        // login page

    driver.findElementById("name").sendKeys("username");  //username textbox

    driver.findElementById("password").sendKeys("password"); //password textbox

    driver.findElementById("login").click(); //login button

    waitForPageLoad(driver); //wait for page load to complete -this line fails returning complete quickly- happens most of the time only in ember js app

    try
    {

        driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("App1")).click(); //link to page containing an iframe that loads another ember js application inside it -fails because of page load wait problem

    }
    catch(Exception exception)
    {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }


    sleep(10000);//sleep for 10 seconds.page is loaded completely.

    driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("App1")).click(); //link to page containing an iframe that loads another ember js application inside it -

    switchFrame(driver,"iframe1"); // frame switch happens but the contents of the frame have not been loaded - the frame contains another ember js application

    try
    {

        driver.findElementByLinkText("SettingsPage").click();// this click fails because of the frame not yet loaded problem

    }
    catch(Exception exception)
    {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }

    sleep(10000);//sleep for 10 seconds

    driver.findElementByLinkText("SettingsPage").click();// this click works after waiting for 10 seconds


}


public static void sleep(long milliSeconds)
{
    try
    {
        Thread.sleep(milliSeconds); 
    }
    catch(Exception exception)
    {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void waitForPageLoad(ChromeDriver driver)
{
    JavascriptExecutor executor=(JavascriptExecutor) driver;

    long startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();

    long timeout=10000;

    String readyState="";

    while((System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime) < timeout)
    {
        readyState=(String)executor.executeScript("return document.readyState");

        if(readyState.equals("complete"))
        {
            break;
        }

        sleep(1000);
    }

}



public static void switchFrame(ChromeDriver driver,String frameid)
{

    WebDriverWait frameWait=new WebDriverWait(driver,25);

    try
    {
        frameWait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.id(frameid)));
    }
    catch(Exception exception)
    {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

Comment: There can be two things 1. after switching to frame just give sleep(20) (20 sec) and print one statement , so if the statement is printed on console , you are inside the frame .   2. May be there are nested iframe , just check.

Comment: `frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt()` never claimed to wait for the content to be fully loaded! Wrapping Selenium's waits in `try..catch` is bad practice and usually leads to problems; that would be the first thing to remove, so you can see what is actually going on.

Comment: the frame switch is happening correctly.i have verified by waiting 10 seconds and then clicking on the element i need and it works fine.My problem is how do i know that the contents of the iframe have been loaded instead of using sleep @cruisepandey